# Cakephp, JQuery JCarousel Lite, Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, jcarousel

I am using the following code to make an unordered list into a carousel with jcarousel lite and jquery:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery-1.4.2.min','jquery.easing.1.1','jcarousellite_1.0.1.pack','jquery.mousewheel.min'), array('inline' => false)); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Html->scriptStart(array('inline' => false)); ?>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".mouseWheelButtons .jCarouselLite").jCarouselLite({
                btnNext: ".mouseWheelButtons .next",
                btnPrev: ".mouseWheelButtons .prev",
                mouseWheel: true,
                circular: false,
                start: 0,
                visible: 5,
                easing: "easein"
            });
        });
    <?php echo $this->Html->scriptEnd(); ?>
```

However I'm getting the following javascript error in firebug:

```
a[0] is undefined
```

Does anyone know what is causing the error.
I am using the packed version of jcarousel lite.

The thing is that the code worked in cakephp 1.2 but now i'm using 1.3 and I have updated the syntax using scriptstart, scriptEnd and Html->script.

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML for the carousel?

Answer (score 1):

OK I found what was wrong.  I seems like all errors are simpler than they initially look.

Everything was set up perfectly however I had forgotten to include the list-item tags. :)

Comment: you should be more specific on what solved your problem by posting code before and after for people who have the same problem

Comment: I had the same error when the markup was `<ul></ul>`. I did as @ion suggested `<ul><li></li></ul>` and everything worked again. I had empty `<ul>` because the markup was autogenerated and no images were in the gallery.

Answer (score 1):

The reference id or class of **div** must be the immediate parent of **ul** tag

*Script*

```
$('.rssBody').jCarouselLite({
       auto: 800,
       speed: 1000
    });
```

*Html*

```
<div class="rssBody">
    <ul>
        <li>text</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```